# NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/identitytoolkit/GitkitClientException

Tags: java, exception, gitkit

I'm using google identity toolkit to make a library. When I give this library to others, their app crashes at startup complaining that `NoClassDefFoundError` on `GitkitClientException`.

To me this is strange because:

1. The `GitkitClientException.class` is in the final jar (in fact this happens to Spring Boot application we well)
2. I checked every method, none of my public method throws a `GitkitClientException`. My understanding is, if the Exception is handled internally and not thrown. The library user should not need the dependency.

EDIT:
I know when the library user add `gitkitclient` as their dependency as well they will not have this crash. But I really want this to be transparent.

The final fat jar looks like this: (this is a dropwizard app)

`├── ch
│

├── com
│   ├── google
│   │      ├── common
│   │      ├── identitytoolkit 
│   │

│   └── fasterxml
├── META_INF
├── net
│   └── models.go
├── org
└── about.html
└── jetty-dir.css`

Comment: How is the GitKit library packaged into your distributed jar?

Comment: @JimGarrison my jar is a normal jar, only contains my classes. But I also distribute a pom file. So in the library user's maven, they use this jar and pom locally, and use maven shade plugin to generate a fat jar. I can see the GitkitClientException in the final fat jar.

Comment: WHERE in the jar?  In a jar-within-the-final-jar, or in the normal package hierarchy?  Clearly the classloader on the subject system cannot find the class, so it's not where it can be found.

Comment: @JimGarrison you make perfect sense. I have two application, in the spring boot jar, it is under /BOOT-INF/lib/. In the dropwizard fat jar, it is in normal package hierarchy. Both of them complain about the same class.

Comment: Without a lot more information (i.e. jar listing showing all the pertinent structure), pom.xml, and probably other stuff like Spring Boot config, I doubt anyone will be able to help.